# How to use nginx to cache the real-time audio stream(audio/mpeg)?

Tags: caching, nginx, audio-streaming

Now i have a real time audio stream such as [this one](http://some.audiosite.com/fm), but the overloads will be terrible and the stream server will crash if tens of Thousand of users come to visite it directly.

Some guys say Making use of nginx's cache is a possible solution, Anyone knows the detail message about hwo to config the nginx server?

By the way, the content-type of the stream is "audio/mpeg".

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx cannot cache a progressive audio stream.  Nginx' caching is built for caching normal file responses.  If the response never finishes (which it doesn't for a real-time progressive audio stream), then there is never anything to cache.  Besides, if 10k users is too much for your audio server, it's likely too much for Nginx as well.

If you really do have 10k simultaneous listeners, what you need is a CDN.  There are many to choose from, depending on your specific needs and budget constraints.

If you want to do the hosting yourself, you'll need a few servers and software such as [Icecast](http://icecast.org/).

Comment: Thank you Brad. If Nginx cannot cache a progressive audio stream. How a CDN could do it? In my mind, a CDN can only cache normal static files too.

Comment: @luckyee With any streaming server, nothing is cached.  The data is buffered and sent to the clients as it comes in.  Most CDNs support operating in this mode.

Comment: Icecast may be a good choice if it does support progressive audio stream.

Comment: @luckyee That's all Icecast does.

Comment: I'm sorry to trouble you again. Since my english is not good, after I read the documents of Icecast, I have two question more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501726/icecast-relay-stream-can-buffer-a-progressive-audio-stream). Thank you.