# Icecast relay stream can buffer a progressive audio stream

Tags: buffer, icecast

After reading the documents of icecast, I have two questions:

1) I'm not sure the icecast server can buffer audio streams, if It does can, How about using relaying?

2) If i have many dynamic relay servers to proxy, How to config the config file? I mean I have to change the config file dynamicly, since i have not sean that icecast supports the regular expression such as /realtime(\d+) to match all the realtime stations.

Comment: You want to set up an Icecast reflector of sorts?  Dynamically relaying existing streams?  `http://your-icecast-server/relay?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsome-other-server%2Fstream`  Something like that?

Comment: Yes, something like that. But does the icecast supports paramters? I hava many realtime radio streams, and they just come from different urls.

Comment: Icecast doesn't, but I have a project that can.  AudioPump Server can do this.  It isn't generally available at the moment, but if you are interested we can work something out.  Can you elaborate on what your specific needs are though?  I want to make sure your needs are beyond Icecast first.  If you connect to streams on-demand, then there is no additional buffering since that would require the server to have connected to the stream before the request came in.  Why not relay all of your streams all the time?

Comment: OK, I have a project aimed to help radio stations to broadcast their real time audio streams, And they have their own broadcast web address, However some hot programs have tens of thansands audiences you know, I think i have to relay their stream for perfermance. Besides, they will upload audio files such as mp3s as well.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to become a streaming CDN yourself.

Comment: Here is my relay config sample:  <relay>
         <server>other site</server>
            <port>8000</port>
           <mount>/fm</mount>
           <relay-shoutcast-metadata>0</relay-shoutcast-metadata>
           <on-demand>1</on-demand>
   </relay>.   Do you mean to change to <on-demand>0</on-demand>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Icecast does buffer streams.  When a client connects, the buffer data is flushed as fast as Icecast can loop around and send data.

Icecast can also relay existing streams.  From [the documentation](http://www.icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.1.0/icecast2_relay.html):

```
<relay>
    <server>192.168.1.11</server>
    <port>8001</port>
    <mount>/example.ogg</mount>
    <local-mount>/different.ogg</local-mount>
    <relay-shoutcast-metadata>0</relay-shoutcast-metadata>
</relay>
```

Now, as for doing this on-the-fly, as far as I know there is no way to do this in Icecast.

Comment: Thanks, Do you think can a proxy or reverse proxy such as nginx between the icecast server and relay servers slove the problem?

Comment: @luckyee What problem?  You haven't described in enough detail what it is that you're trying to do.  Nginx is of no use to you here, as I said in your previous questions.  The response of a stream never finishes, and Nginx cannot stream the same response to multiple clients at once.  If you disabled its caching, you would require a connection to the upstream server for each connection to the Nginx server, completely defeating its purpose.  Yes, setting Icecast up as a relay is what you need to do, but 10k listeners is an awful lot so you will need many relays.

Comment: OK，Beside the real time radio stream, what's the better choice when i just want to play static mp3 files, nginx or icecast? what's the differences?

Comment: I mean i can put mp3 files in the nginx's static file directories, and users can access them directly or I can put the static Url int the html tags such as <audio src="http://***/abc.mp3" />

Comment: You can't play static files with Icecast... you would want a web server like Nginx.

Comment: I have tried to play static mp3 files width Icecast and nginx, Both work fine, I have no idea which is the better choice. Your advice is Nginx because Nginx can take more user accesses than Icecast?

Comment: Here is [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24522516/how-to-choice-a-server-to-cache-and-play-static-mp3-files-for-many-client-users).

Comment: @luckyee Show me your Icecast configuration for serving static MP3 files.

Comment: the config file: <paths>
        ......
        <webroot>/data/web/audio/files</webroot>
        ......
    </paths>, then I put some mp3 in the /data/web/audio/files/ directory, and It works. You can try [this](http://www.epintan.com:8000/father.mp3)

Comment: @luckyee Sure, you can serve files like that if you want to.  It's not really what Icecast was designed for though.  You can benchmark between it and Nginx, but I suspect Nginx will win easily.

Comment: Thank you very much Brad! And I will always be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

I found one of the solutions which is free & simple (tried & tested), but with some limitations.
Rocket Streaming Audio Server
https://www.rocketbroadcaster.com/streaming-audio-server/
It really allows you to relay https stream to http (stream mirroring). Configuring the app is simple. It relays streams 'as is' (without re-encoding), but in free version you can stream only to 100 listeners.